# We've had a lot of people stop by our booth -> "Have + people +stop" why is the verb form stop not stopping?

Tags: modal-verbs

please help me with this.

So I heard today that a native american person said "We've had a lot of people stop by our booth"

and I though it should be "we've had a lot of people stopping by our booth"

Answer (score 1):

When describing something that you [experienced](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-something-done) in the past, you can use the **-ing** form of the verb or the infinitive without **to**.

Generally we use the infinitive without **to** for a completed action

> We had a strange man come to the door yesterday - *it happened once, and is completed*

We use the **-ing** form for things happening over a period of time.

> We had a strange man hanging around in the street outside our house last week - *over a period of time*

In your sentence, the speaker could use **stop** if they want to indicate that something happened in the past and is completed, or **stopping** if it happened continuously over the period of time that they are talking about.